# To pass value of a variable in one function to another function in same class

Tags: php, kohana

I have a class `Block_Model` (actually a model in Kohana framework) with 2 methods `input()`and `output()`.

```
class Block_Model extends ORM {
    function input($arg) {
        //...
    }
    function output() {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

The method `input` is called from a function written inside a controller called `Home_Controller` and it passes an argument to the method `input`.

```
class Home_Controller extends Controller {
    function doSomething() {
        $block = new Block_Model();
        //...
        $block->input($val);
        //...
    }
}
```

How can I make the argument passed to `input()` be accessible in the method `output()`?

Comment: Can you give some more detail? You can easily access the variable passed in the input(), by calling the output() and pass the variable inside. But I am confused reading your question. BTW, I am not so familiar with Kohana framework.

Comment: ok please wait, i will make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You'll need private property:

```
class Something{
   private $_variable = "";

   function input( $data ){
      $this->_variable = $data;
      //do the rest of function
   }

   function output(  ){
      //get previously set data
      echo $this->_variable;
   }

}
```

Comment: i used that code silent,    but i used private $_variable; and not private $_variable=''; andd did not work before

Comment: the output() will also be called by a function called getouput() whicjh is inside the controller Home_Controller, then we have to return the value from output function to getoutput(),  like  function output(  ){
     
      return $this->_variable;
   }

Comment: functions are wriiten as public, i mean public input() and public output()

Comment: then on your Home_Controller, prior calling BlockController->output(), you have to call BlockController->_variable = "blablabla". But, before that, you have to set $_variable to public or create setter for it.

Comment: you have model, input() and output(). Now, you have Controller. In your controller, you call both input() and output(), right?

Comment: yes input and output are functions inside Model, and they are called from functions written in Controller

Comment: Then, there shouldn't be any problem with my solution above. If there's a problem. I think I need to see your Controller and Model. Please paste it somewhere (pastebin maybe)

Comment: shall i paste it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @silent's answer, but you can combine setter & getter in one method.

```
protected $_foo;

public function foo($val = NULL)
{
    if ($val === NULL)
    {
        // its a getter!
        return $this->_foo;
    }

    // its a setter 
    $this->_foo = $val;
    // return current object, so it becomes a chainable method
    return $this;
}
```

Now you can use `$value = $object->foo();` and `$object->foo($value)->do_something_else();`

Comment: some value is returned to output() but its not the argument of input() function. There are 2 or 3 return statements used in input() function returning some other values to the Controller class Function . Will that be a problem

Comment: sorry for the delay i  will try to show the code there, Hope no problems if I paste the code there