# Using Global Variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To pass value of a variable in one function to another function in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289352/to-pass-value-of-a-variable-in-one-function-to-another-function-in-same-class)

Can a value of a variable in one function be made available in another function on the same class using "GLOBAL" in PHP. If so please suggest how can this be achieved using Global.

Comment: haven't you asked the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289352/to-pass-value-of-a-variable-in-one-function-to-another-function-in-same-class

Comment: Global? In another function on the same class?  What's the problem with a private class variable?

Comment: actually the variable used in the first function has a value which is the argument being passed to the first function. I want this to be available in second function, Is it possible by using GLOBAL

Comment: @atno @dhaam I believe this may be implemented also by static variable, but it depends on the purpose of this variable dhaam passes. If it will be common across many instances, the better solution would be to use static variable - my answer covers that topic. If this is only about passing variables within one instance, the Codecraft's answer is more suitable than mine.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to make a variable GLOBAL if you're within an object.

```
class myClass {

  public $myVar = "Hello";

  function myFunction() { 
    echo $this->$myVar;
  }

}
```

This is one of the main points of objects - that you can assign different values to variables and get/set those variables within the different methods.  And also that you can create multiple instances of objects each holding different information within the same structure and with the same methods available.

Comment: +1 For actually answering the question. Although in fact this solution does not behave like _global_, because non-static properties change across different instances of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what @Codecraft said (about using public properties), you can use:

- indeed global variable (which is really something you should avoid doing),
- passing values in parameters,
- static variable within class,

Below is the example of using **static variable** (private), because I think this suits your needs best:

```
class MyClass {
    private static $_something;
    public function write() {
        static::$_something = 'ok';
    }
    public function read() {
        return static::$_something;
    }
}

$x = new MyClass();
$x->write();
var_dump($x->read());
```

which outputs:

> string(2) "ok"

This is in fact **something like a global**, but available only from inside your class (because of the keyword "*private*") and **common among *every* instance of the class**. If you use setting some non-static property, it will change across different instances of the class (one object may have different value stored in it than the other object has).

**Comparison of solutions based on static and non-static variables:**

Solution **based on static variable** will give you really **global-like behaviour** (value passed across different instances of the same class):

```
class MyClass {
    private static $_something;
    public function write() {
        static::$_something = 'ok';
    }
    public function read() {
        return static::$_something;
    }
}

// first instance
$x = new MyClass();
$x->write();
// second instance
$y = new MyClass();
var_dump($y->read());
```

which outputs:

> string(2) "ok"

And the solution **based on non-static** variables will look like:

```
class MyClass {
    private $_something;
    public function write() {
        $this->_something = 'ok';
    }
    public function read() {
        return $this->_something;
    }
}

// first instance
$x = new MyClass();
$x->write();
// second instance
$y = new MyClass();
var_dump($y->read());
```

but will output:

> NULL

which means that **in this case the second instance has no value assigned for the variable** you wanted to behave like "global".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a value of a variable in one function can be made available in another function on the same class using "GLOBAL". The following code prints `3`:

```
class Foo
{
  public function f1($arg) {
    GLOBAL $x;
    $x = $arg;
  }
  public function f2() {
    GLOBAL $x;
    return $x;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->f1(3);
echo $foo->f2();
```

However, the usage of global variables is usually a sign of poor design.

Note that while keywords in PHP are case-insensitive, it is custom to use lower case letters for them. Not also that the superglobal array that contains all global variables is called `$GLOBALS`, not `GLOBAL`.

Comment: using global also not achievable